# How to authenticate Clash Royale Player with API token?

Tags: python, api, authentication

Clash Royale has this cool so called "API token" (see the picture) that is more or less "private" and can be used to authenticate the owner of a clash royale account.

This is done by RoyaleAPI (https://help.royaleapi.com/en/rls_verify.html)

But how to they authenticate the players? Is there an API you could pass these parameters to or something? I didn't found ANYTHING on the web :(

Thanks in advance :)

[image: the Clash Royale API token]

Comment: https://developer.clashroyale.com/#/getting-started

Comment: not sure if you understand my problem... your link points to the official clash royale API which you will need to get information about e.g. a player but as I know this API does not allow any interactions with player API tokens from the cr acc settings. Note that there is a difference between the "API token" (thing from the settings) and the "API key" (used by clash royale developers)

Answer (score 0):

In which language do you need your solution?

I've implemented the following functionality. The code is written in GO but you can copy the logic and translate into your language.

The library have the following functionality:

- Login
- Token generation
- Token list
- Token delete

https://github.com/alessiosavi/GoClashRoyale/blob/master/api/auth.go

Comment: still not what I was looking for but thanks.